# Random Access in Array

Tags: java, arrays

I was reading [this](http://www.javatpoint.com/array-in-java), advantages of java, where it states that `random access` is an advantage of arrays in java. I do not understand how can accessing a random element of an array is an advantage. Shouldn't it be a disadvantage?

Why is java allowing to access elements of an array randomly, if the data is stored continuously, shouldn't the data be accessed in an orderly manner?

Comment: Random access means that you can access any array element by it's index in O(1) time.

Comment: Which is why I always suggested the name should be changed to `arbitrary access`, not `random`. Until then, think of it as `arbitrary`.

Comment: @Oleksandr random access doesn't mean that accessing any element of the array at any given point in execution or compilation? even if it is not required

Comment: @iuliu.net please tell more about `arbitrary access`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Random(direct) access implies the ability to access any entry in a array in constant time (independent of its position in the array and of array's size). And that is big advantage.

It is typically contrasted to sequential access. Datastructure has sequential access if we can only visit the values it contains in one particular order.

Comment: ok ok, this explains robustness of java (if i'm not wrong), so why is it called random access, shouldn't it be called sequential access ?

Comment: Because random access enables you to access n-th element of datastructure without iterating over previous (n-1) elements.

Answer (score 0):

**Java array** is an object the contains elements of similar data type. It is a data structure where we store similar elements. We can store only fixed set of elements in a java array.

**Advantage of Java Array**

Code Optimization: It makes the code optimized, we can retrieve or sort the data easily.
Random access: We can get any data located at any index position.

**Disadvantage of Java Array**

Size Limit: We can store only fixed size of elements in the array. It doesn't grow its size at runtime. To solve this problem, collection framework is used in java.

Comment: Rahul, please read my question  `I do not understand how can accessing a random element of an array is an advantage. Shouldn't it be a disadvantage?`

Comment: Here in this context random element means that any element you know exists in the in the array by its index

Answer (score 0):

It means any element in an array has constant access time O(1). Arrays store it's elements in contiguous memory locations. Arrays store objects with fixed size and any object can be accessed by calculating the offset which is (size*index) instead of traversing the entire array sequentially.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on your use, if you want to access data again, i recommend to see Maps ou HashMaps using , it's the most simple way to work.

If you want to sort an array you can use Arrays.sort(...);